# How to sendmail in Python using Mimemultipart

Tags: python, email

I'm a newbie to Python so having some difficulty in sending mail using python script .I'm using mime and smtplib .For some reason I'm getting unable to send and my mail doesn't have any body .attaching the code.
Any idea ??

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

hostname='hello'

sender = 'xx@xx.com'
receivers = ['vholla@xx.com']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers
msg['Subject'] = "Upgrade started for"+hostname+"."


try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mail.xxx.com',25)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
   print "Successfully sent email"
except:
        print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this option works by `postfix`:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect('localhost') # connect to the SMTP server
doc = "<html><h1>Test title</h1></html>"
while True:
    msg = MIMEText( doc, _subtype='html', _charset='utf-8' )
    s.sendmail('xx@xx.com', ['vholla@xx.com'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```